# How to create multiple monaco javascript editors so they don't share a global namespace?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'd like to have multiple Monaco editors on a page, but each with the own set of globals. Variables created in one editor shouldn't be available as types in an another.

I've tried setting `monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({isolatedModules: true})`, but that didn't seem to effect these shared global types.

**How can I create multiple monaco javascript editors so they don't share a global namespace?**

```js
// set up code for the Monaco Playground:
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const container1 = document.createElement("div");
const container2 = document.createElement("div");
container1.style.height="200px";
container1.style.border = "solid 2px black";
container1.style.marginBottom = "16px";
container2.style.height="200px";
container2.style.border = "solid 2px black";
container.appendChild(container1);
container.appendChild(container2);



// actual code:
monaco.editor.create(container1, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(`const abc = 123;`,
        "javascript",
        monaco.Uri.parse("js:editor1.js")
    )
});

monaco.editor.create(container2, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(
        "const value = abc; // should be typed as `any`, but is typed as `123` instead!",
        "javascript",
        monaco.Uri.parse("js:editor2.js")
    )
});
```

Try it in the playground: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html

Answer (score 1):

I found some discussion in https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/262 .

My temporary solution is to add `export {}` at the beginning of the code. Hopefully I can find a more elegant way to solve the problem.

```js
// set up code for the Monaco Playground:
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const container1 = document.createElement("div");
const container2 = document.createElement("div");
container1.style.height = "200px";
container1.style.border = "solid 2px black";
container1.style.marginBottom = "16px";
container2.style.height = "200px";
container2.style.border = "solid 2px black";
container.appendChild(container1);
container.appendChild(container2);



// actual code:
monaco.editor.create(container1, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(
        `export {}\nconst abc = 123;`,
        "javascript",
        monaco.Uri.parse("js:editor1.js"),
    )
});

monaco.editor.create(container2, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(
        "export {}\nconst a = abc; // should be typed as `any`, but is typed as `123` instead!",
        "javascript",
        monaco.Uri.parse("js:editor2.js")
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in my case changing the setting you mentioned fixed it:

Old:

> monaco.languages.typescript.**javascriptDefaults**.setCompilerOptions({isolatedModules:
> true})

New:

> monaco.languages.typescript.**typescriptDefaults**.setCompilerOptions({isolatedModules:
> true})